# Regression prediction with combination of predictors

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have one linear regression model: y ~ x1 + x2 (1)
and now let x3 = x1+x2, x4=x1-x2, to form a new regression y ~ x3 + x4 (2),
would the prediction of (1) and (2) be the same?

If I add L1 regularization to both models, would the prediction of (1) and (2) be the same?

Answer (score 0):

That's not code question, its a substitution problem :
y = (x1+x2) + (x1-x2) = 2x1 ...

Comment: y = 2 +2 = 4 ,  y = 2*2 =4, So as you can see it depends, but yes you can have the same prediction.

Comment: It's not a code question, it is a statistical question. Please show some respect and provide robust mathematical proof if you understand the concept of regression model, thanks,

Comment: the answer is provided in the equation above . You can have multiple equations :

Comment: y = w1[x1] + w2[x2]  If your fitting works , maybe with just one weight you can achieve the result, if you perform a Lasso regression that penalizes by weight (big ones )  w2~0 , thus creating only the common y = w1*x1 +b equation. Your question also states that a combination of two things can be the same as 2 times one thin, which again is consistent. So yes, you can get the same equation, prediction. If you are trying to see which how many params are necessary I suggest a Lasso regression that does not only fits, but makes very small (close to zero) the weights that are not necessary.

Comment: But in your question you are saying that x1 and x2 are the weights ( I suppose) so if the alpha you choose is correct and you choose the substitution that you describe, you can get the same result.

Comment: Hey, x1 and x2 are vectors, if x1 = [1,1,1,1]' and x2 = [4,3,2,1]' then x3 = [5,4,3,2]', and x4 = [-3, -2, -1,0]'. We still have regress y on two predictors x3, x4.